# Solving the discrete logic equations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Let $x, y, z, t ∈ \{0,1\}$.
>
> Solve the following equation:
>
> $(x \wedge y) \implies (z \vee t) = 0.$

I have done this,

[image]

I don't see any $0$ in the expression which the question talks about.

Comment: What do they mean by solve the equations? Like assigning values to x,y,yz,t (either 0 or 1) such that the expression is false? Also note that you need $2^4 = 16$ rows

Answer (score 1):

There should be $16$ rows in this table for all the combination of $0, 1$ values of $x, y, z, t$. Then notice those values of $x, y, z, t$ for which the expression evaluates to $0$.

Comment: okay. got it bro.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using De Morgan's law and duality principle.

x ^ y = 1 <=> z v t = 0 for some z and t.

Similarly, x ^ y = 0 <=> z v t = 1 for some z and t.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $x,y,z,t\in\{0,1\}.$
>
> Solve the following equation:
>
> $(x \land y) \implies (z \lor t)=0$.

**Hint:**

Look at the general format of the equality: $P \implies Q = 0$.

The only time an implication is false is.....

This in turn implies....